# how do I convert a large array of rgb values to a hex array

Tags: javascript, arrays, hex, rgb

their current format is [r,g,b,r,g,b,...] I need an array of hex values like this [#rgb,#rgb,...]
its specifically an array of 797 arrays of 1176 items each
it should be 797 arrays of 392 items each
I found functions to convert rgb to hex if formatted like this
[[r,g,b][r,g,b],...]
but the array I have is not broken into smaller chunks this way
so ether something that can convert the whole thing of something that a can break it up into sets of three  I can just use a foreach loop
im unsure how to approach this

Comment: Relevant: [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8495687)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

It is not clear if you had an array of arrays

```js
const rgbToHex = (r, g, b) => `#${((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1)}`;

const convertArrayToHexColors = (array) => array.map(subArray => 
  Array.from({ length: subArray.length / 3 }, (_, i) => 
    rgbToHex(subArray[i * 3], subArray[i * 3 + 1], subArray[i * 3 + 2])
  )
);


const hexColorArray = convertArrayToHexColors(exampleArray);
console.log(hexColorArray)
```

```html
<script>
const exampleArray = [
    [255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255], 
    [128, 128, 128, 192, 192, 192, 64, 64, 64] 
];
</script>
```

Comment: yes this is very helpful and exactly what im looking for!